# How get only the styles declared in a stylesheet's declaration and not the computed ones?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I loop through `document.styleSheets` to find the css rule matched by `.myClass`, I get more style values than the ones actually declared.

For example, with this CSS:

```
.myClass { border: none; }
```

I would get all of these rules:

```
border: medium none
borderBottom: medium none
borderBottomColor: -moz-use-text-color
MozBorderBottomColors: none
borderBottomStyle: none
borderBottomWidth: medium
borderColor: -moz-use-text-color
borderImage: none
borderImageSource: none
borderImageSlice: 100% 100% 100% 100%
borderImageWidth: 1 1 1 1
borderImageOutset: 0 0 0 0
borderImageRepeat: stretch stretch
borderLeft: medium none
borderLeftColor: -moz-use-text-color
MozBorderLeftColors: none
borderLeftStyle: none
borderLeftWidth: medium
borderRight: medium none
borderRightColor: -moz-use-text-color
MozBorderRightColors: none
borderRightStyle: none
borderRightWidth: medium
borderStyle: none
borderTop: medium none
borderTopColor: -moz-use-text-color
MozBorderTopColors: none
borderTopStyle: none
borderTopWidth: medium
borderWidth: medium
color: rgb(200, 200, 200)
MozBorderImage: none
```

How do I find only the rule I actually set in the stylesheet?

Comment: Your question cant be any more vague. Can you please either post some code or elaborate a little?

Comment: it's under rule.cssText

Comment: @dandavis He's probably looking for a parsed version of that... Or at least a parsed version that keeps declarations collapsed.

Comment: @Bart: right, one has to use a parser on the cssText to find the properties w/o shorthands and inheriteds. or even a naive regexp would likely suffice

Comment: @dandavis thank you, it appears that will work. Can you post that as the answer?